# Prevent extensions installation

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I work in an IT department, and we allow the use of vscode. However, certain extensions do not suit us within the framework of our security policy.

We would like to prevent users from installing all available extensions, and only allow some that we have validated. I tried adding in the "settings.json" file the parameter

```
"extensions.allowMarketplace": false
```

but it doesn't work. Do you know another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This request has been made several times and Microsoft's answers
were generally positive, although there is no date for its
implementation.

Some such requests were :

- [Implement a policy-settings mechanism for approving/blocking extensions #84756](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84756)
- [ADMX policies for controlling VSCode extensions #170840](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/170840)
- [Group Policy to deactivate extentions? #156568](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/156568)

You will need to implement such a mechanism yourself.

An idea would be to block in the corporate firewall the
[Visual Studio Code Market Place](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode)
and only white-list the extensions that you allow.

This solution would only work for locations within the
corporate wall, not for example if employees take their computer
home. Unless you create GPOs for setting firewall rules
on the users' computers.